# decoding json from ustream api with python

Tags: python, json, api, decode, simplejson

I'm trying to use simplejson to parse a request from the ustream data api, and I get this error when decoding. I'm new to the json library in python, so i'm not sure where to begin working towards a solution.

```
>>> import simplejson as json
>>> import requests as requests
>>> r = requests.get("http://api.ustream.tv/json/stream/popular/search/all?key=y
ourDevKey")
>>> in_json = None
>>> json.loads(in_json)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson-2.3.0-py2.7.egg\simplejson\__in
it__.py", line 413, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson-2.3.0-py2.7.egg\simplejson\deco
der.py", line 402, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

any help?

Comment: `json.loads(in_json)` the in_json `expected string or buffer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing this :

```
>>> in_json = None
>>> json.loads(in_json)
```

you ask json to parse `None`... and None is not a JSon object, that's the cause of your problem.

I think it would be better to do something like this

```
>>> r = requests.get("http://api.ustream.tv/json/stream/popular/search/all?key=y
ourDevKey")
>>> json.loads(r.content)
```

Comment: oh wow, can't believe i missed that. Sorry for the dumb question